# Can I access non-environment Team City parameters from a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell-3.0, teamcity-9.0

I want to access this parameter: %teamcity.tool.NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT.nupkg%

It works fine when the parameter is used in a script that is manually entered into the PowerShell build step.

However I am using script files (*.ps1) and I would like to access from the script file.

It's possible with environment variables as they are added to the PowerShell runner. e.g. %build.number% can be used in script file like this : $env:build_number

I know I can setup a build parameter (in the TeamCity configuration settings) and that will be added to PowerShell runner.
But that seems a bit of a faff, repetition of data, and just another setting to forget to set.

Is there any way to access %teamcity.tool.NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT.nupkg% from a PowerShell script such as: 
$teamcity:tool_NuGet_CommandLine_DEFAULT_nupkg

But so it works:)

Thanks.